# Are there infinitely many $n$ such that $n$ and $2n+1$ are both prime numbers?

Tags: number-theory

It seems that there are many such $n$. For example, the following are such $n$'s under $4000$.

> 2 3 5 11 23 29 41 53 83 89 113 131 173 179 191 233 239 251 281 293 359 419 431 443 491 509 593 641 653 659 683 719 743 761 809 911 953 1013 1019 1031 1049 1103 1223 1229 1289 1409 1439 1451 1481 1499 1511 1559 1583 1601 1733 1811 1889 1901 1931 1973 2003 2039 2063 2069 2129 2141 2273 2339 2351 2393 2399 2459 2543 2549 2693 2699 2741 2753 2819 2903 2939 2963 2969 3023 3299 3329 3359 3389 3413 3449 3491 3539 3593 3623 3761 3779 3803 3821 3851 3863 3911

But my question is, is it known that there are infinitely many such $n$?

Comment: That other question is not a duplicate. That question asks if $f(n)=2n+1$ does $f(n),f^2(n),\dots,f^{k}(n),\dots$ eventually yield a prime. I would not be surprised if this is a duplicate, but whoever marked this for closure found the wrong old post.

Comment: Someone tried to close this as a duplicate of another question. While they are superficially similar, they are not the same question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Such primes are known as Sophie Germain primes. It is unknown if there is an infinite amount, but we nonetheless conjecture that up to $x$ there is asymptotically
$$
C \frac{x}{(\log x)^2}
$$
such primes, where $C$ is a certain absolute constant. Sophie Germain primes were first discovered by Sophie Germain in connection with Fermat's Last Theorem. She proved that $x^n + y^n = z^n$ has no non-trivial solutions when $n$ is a Sophie Germain prime.

Comment: Wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime

Comment: Except that Wikipedia doesn't mention the connection with Fermat's Last theorem...

Comment: I didn't mean it as a substitute for your answer, only as a place to go next :)